# Logo disappears when changing current page multiple times

Tags: node.js

I'm fairly new to NodeJS and currently facing a very strange problem. When changing the current page multiple times the logo (/an image) suddenly disappears.

To keep this short: here's a gif showing the behaviour; http://files.nehalist.io/bug.gif

And here's the complete source code: https://github.com/nehalist/hayes

Node version: 0.10.28

Any ideas?

Comment: in the network tab of the dev tools do you see any 404's or other errors?

Comment: Okay, I've waited quite some time (around 5 - 6 minutes). The image is pending first, but loads after some time. After switching pages again, it disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing that is weird is that your image src has a relative path: https://github.com/nehalist/hayes/blob/master/app/views/sidebar.hbs#L4

It probably should be: `<img src="/images/onion_48x48.png">`

Which may not actually fix the issue, but will mean that the image will keep getting fetched from the same location meaning your browser can cache the image.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but you were right - it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  The problem was the favicon request; my PageController tried to resolve the following query: `SELECT id, title, slug, content, FROM pages WHERE slug = favicon.ico`. I have no idea why, but this request took quite a long time and after some requests (around 6) it blocked the image.

Here the modified PageController:

```
PageController = {
index: function(req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        res.end();

        return ;
    }
//...
```